# find by css selector doesn't work correctly

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, behat, mink

I have scenario

```
 /**
 * @Then I click on suggestion element
 */
public function iClickOnSuggestionElement()
{
   $el =  $this->getSession()->getPage()
        ->find('css', '.autocomplete-suggestion[data-index=0]');
    if(!$el){
        throw new Exception('Element not found!');
    }

    $el->click();
}
```

when i run behat tests i get errors:
 Curl error thrown for http POST to http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session/b0903fe0-1327-4833-b4fc-ee52ac8bac29/moveto with params: {"element":"7"}

```
  The requested URL returned error: 500 Internal Server Error (WebDriver\Exception\CurlExec)
```

I guess it is because of ->find('css')

## behat.yml

```
      default:
        suites:
        guest_features:
              paths:    [ %paths.base%/features/web ]
              filters:  { role: guest }
              contexts: [ GuestContext ]

        user_features:
            paths:    [ %paths.base%/features/web ]
            filters:  { role: member }
            contexts: [ MemberContext ]

        groupled_features:
            paths:    [ %paths.base%/features/web ]
            filters:  { role: grouplead}
            contexts: [ GroupleadContext ]

        admin_features:
            paths:    [ %paths.base%/features/web ]
            filters:  { role: admin }
            contexts: [ AdminContext ]

 extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension:
        base_url: someUrl
        browser_name: firefox
        selenium2:
                capabilities: { "browser": "firefox", "version": "24"}
        goutte: ~
```

i use selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0

p/s i have already found familiar issue (https://github.com/minkphp/MinkSelenium2Driver/issues/200 ) but downgrading the version of browser doesn't make an affect.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

capabilities: { "browser": "firefox", "version": "24"}

You are using such an old version of firefox? You should think about compatibility of firefox, firefoxdriver and selenium. If you are using selenium 2.45.0 then you need the latest firefox version and the latest firefox driver.